# XmlSpy: Test XSLT W locally with static Java Methods

Tags: java, xslt, altova, xmlspy

I develop XSLT mappings in XMLSpy for usage on an integration platform. There it is possible to execute static java methods which are prefixed with a namespace corresponding to the java package The java methods are used to extend built in XPath functions. The mappings can be executed in the runtime of the integration server.
Now it would be great if testing could be done locally in XMLSpy.

Now the technical question:

Is this possible if the jar file with the static methods is available? If so, how?

Thank you so much for any advice.

Comment: The docs https://www.altova.com/manual/XMLSpy/spyenterprise/fxmisc_java.html suggest the tool has support for extension functions done in Java. Whether you will have the same extension function API and mapping of types like in your integration platform is something I can't tell.